# Compare 2 tables by Rows values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check if supplier can make this article, by comparing field but there is a range too

eg: capability is layer_min=2 layer_max=20 but article has 12 which should be between min and max otherwise cant make it. and if one row fails it should exclude that site_id

Capabilities

```
1   surface Gold    1
2   surface SIlver  1
3   size_x  100 1
4   size_y  200 1
5   layer_min   2   1
6   layer_max   20  1
7   surface Gold    2
8   surface Copper  2
9   size_x  90  2
10  size_y  100 2
11  layer_min   12  2
12  layer_max   32  2
```

Article

```
1   surface Gold
3   size_x  100
4   size_y  200
5   layer_count 16
```

this article should return only site 1 because it meets:
Surface Gold
Size x = 100
Size y = 200
layercount =16 (greater that min, less than max)

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0471c20b15e7c2af002e48bcb9eb55ec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a table where the item is specified, if the comparison should be done by equality or by range.
Example
surface: equality, layer: from - to

This would be the base of the work

You can also change the table 'Article'

```
CREATE TABLE 'article' (
  'id' int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'key' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  'value' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  'from' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  'to' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY ('id')
```

Then

```
SELECT * 
FROM `capabilities` LEFT JOIN article ON capabilities.`key` = article.`key` 
where capabilities.`value` = article.`value` 
or (capabilities.`value` between article.`from` and article.`to`
```

Comment: Article table cannot be changed, normally values comes from api in key/value pair.

Comment: as I said at the beginning and if you know the possible keys you can create your own table.  in this way it can be solved in the query.  Another option is to write a procedure that searches for example key = 'xxxx_' and assumes that it is a range.